# Inter-Process communication in compute shaders

Tags: opengl, gpu, compute-shader

How do I write a code to facilitate common shared memory for communication between multiple shaders as well as processes within them in python?

Comment: You can use "Shader Storage Buffer Object" (SSBO). This is GPU memory, which can be accessed by any shader. You can load this buffer to CPU as well (glGetBufferSubData()).

Comment: When you say "between multiple shaders", do you mean between multiple separate programs or multiple invocations in the same dispatch call?

Comment: Between multiple separate programs